# eclipse autocomplete

Tags: eclipse

I have noticed that qtCreator handles the auto-completion much better than eclipse.

For example, if I have a line that says `object.firstItem()` and put my cursor between `.` and `f`, and then delete the `first` word (thus becoming `object.|item()`)  and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and choose `secondItem()`, qtCreator guesses `object.secondItem();`, whereas eclipse chooses `object.firstItem()Item()`.

There could well be other features that are present in qtCreator, too, but not in eclipse, though it's the only one I really noticed. But why not share all good ideas since they all are open source ? I would be interested in all good features of qtCreator and eclipse combined.

Is there a way to have such a behaviour in eclipse too, through configuration or through a plugin ?

Answer (score 8):

This feature is supported by Eclipse, too. (Or more specifically, the Eclipse Java Development Tools.)

Just hold down the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key when selecting the item from the list of proposed completions to toggle between *inserting* and *overwriting* completion mode.

To change the default behaviour, go to *Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist* and change the top-most radio button from "Completion inserts" to "Completion overwrites".

Comment: Thanks, your solution does help, but it would be nice if it was smart enough to figure it out automatically if the following text actually matched the ending of the selected completion code.