# Eclipse content assist: don't add params if they are already there

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

So sometimes in my project I'll type out the method but end up needing to import the class or static import.  For example:

```
assertTrue(true);
```

I then want to go back and "complete" assertTrue so that it brings in my import for me.  however I get

```
assertTrue(arg0)(true);
```

Which is annoying.  Back in the olden days there was an option not to do this if the params were already there.

Is there a way to disable this while still keeping param completions for times when they are not there?

Comment: Not sure this is what you want, but you can hold down Ctrl (or configure Eclipse to do this by default, and hold Ctrl when you want the standard behavior). See [this (my) answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819925/eclipse-autocomplete/14820386#14820386).

Comment: That is what I want.  I think insert and overwrite aren't exactly the correct terms for the behavior.  Neither actually delete your old params which I think is where my confusion came in.

Thanks